# Azure batch - run multiple commands from command line on linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, azure-batch

At the beginning, I created a pool with the following configuration:

> "Publisher": "microsoft-ads"
>
> "Offer": "linux-data-science-vm"
>
> "Sku": "linuxdsvm"

Then I want "start.sh" file to be copied and run on VM.
So, I need to change permissions, to allow execution of start.sh and then execute it.

```
chmod +x start.sh && ./start.sh
```

When I run it manually from terminal it works.
But Azure Batch writes the following in the stderr.txt:

> chmod: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory

Is there some way to run multiple commands from single Command Line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes, sure. I thought that there were some differences between Azure Batch command line and Linux Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start the command with `/bin/bash -c`and then put the command in double quotes, like this:
`/bin/bash -c "chmod +x start.sh && ./start.sh"`

Comment: It works, thank you! Just luck of experience with Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is an old answer, but it was still relevant/helpful for me today!